# How do you complete the quest “Recent Events on M4-78”?

Tags: steam, mods, star-wars-kotor-2

This is pertaining to Star Wars KOTOR 2 and the M4-78 Enhancement Project. I am currently on the planet M4-78 and am about to finish it but this one quest ”Recent Events on M4-78” is hard to finish. I am to a point where I have spoken to a droid named E1-07 but I forgot where this droid is and I am unsure of which droid I need to speak to next. I don’t know how close I am to finishing the quest. Any ideas on how to proceed? It’s not necessary for Steam Achievements.